# textarea line break jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have got a button 'edit description' when I click on it text disappear   and appear

```
        if (id == 'commedit') jQuery(this).html('<textarea>'+jQuery(this).text()+'</textarea>');
        else if (id == 'commsave') {
            jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).find('textarea').val());
        }
```

In MySql I have this text - `"tetee<br>afafaf<br>afafaf<br>afsafsasfasf"` in view it dispays with line breaks but when I click 'edit' in text area which come with Jquery text appear without lines and when I click save it also appear in my description field in one long line without line breaks. So I need your help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`<br>` are html breaks. You want `\n` in a textarea.

```
jQuery(this).html().replace(/<br>/gi,"\n")
```

When you save, you want to change it back to breaks and use html() instead of text();

```
var elem = jQuery(this);
if (id === 'commedit') {
    var text = jQuery(this).html().replace(/<br>/gi,"\n");
    elem.html('<textarea>'+ text +'</textarea>');
} else if (id === 'commsave') {
    var html = elem.find('textarea').val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
    elem.html(html);
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QAkja/)

Comment: May I ask you how to do textarea heigh for text height. How to get text height and after pass this value to textarea height. I tried this .html('<textarea style="height: 400px;">'+jQuery(this).html().replace(/<br>/gi,"\n")+'</textarea>') and it works but now height is static but I want to do dynamic

Comment: what does height value relate too?

Comment: today I noticed that br now safe good but spaces not in view...is it possible to make many spaces vissible?

Comment: maybe you can show in your example on JSFiddle how to keep spaces (more then one) and line breaks (this already work)

Comment: You would have to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`